# Get Callback reference for a ongoing downloading task

Tags: android, download

I have a downloading manager where I pass the file url and also the callback which has methods like onStart(), progress(Integer..)

Now when I click a file to download, I start a new activity where Manager starts the downloading in background and callback methods are called appropriately. If I close this activity and again click on the same file the file downloading start again while the previous one is going on.

**What I want is to show the previous file not a new download by getting any reference or something**

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by my self and to ans my own question.
Here it goes..

So what I did is override the **beforeExecute()** and **afterExecute()** method of MyThreadPoolExecutor Class by extending it with ThreadPoolExeutor.

Now I saved the runnable task in a HashMap in beforeExecute and then removed it in AfterExecute. So When I again open the Downloading activity , there i checked if the task is already executing by checking the task from the HashMap i saved in MyThreadPoolExecutor. So if the task is already executing i just updated the callback reference via setter. So now the new callback methods get called.

**Note:** In downloading activity I am creating a Task which extends runnable interface and this task has some sort of tag thats how I can identify if its already running or not.